# KB4457145: Windows Server 2008 R2 September 2018 Security Update

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-update

I am having difficulty installing the September and October Windows Server 2008 R2 2018 Security Updates, KB4457145 and KB4462915. Every time I install the updates, one at a time, they install successfully. However, upon reboot, they revert changes and fail to complete the update. I have tried using the Windows Update application, downloading the updates directly from the MS Update Catalog and installing manually. I have also tried installing and booting into Safe Mode. Not sure what else to do.

[image: Failure configuring Windows updates Reverting Changes. Do not turn off you computer.]

Comment: Hi, please post the %windir%\Windowsupdate.log

Comment: Why are you installing the Security Monthly Quality Rollup for September, and the Security Only Update for October? Why not just install the Security Monthly Quality Rollup for October?

Comment: @Greg Askew: None of these work. I get the same error above for all of them. Besides, I am installing what Nessus says I am missing, which is not the Security Only update, they should be both the Quality Rollups for both months, but I'll double check the KB numbers on Monday.

Comment: @ yagmoth555: I will get this posted Monday.

Comment: @yagmoth555 how much of the log did you want to see? I have a 2 hour window from one of the days when I was attempting the update. About 690 lines.

Comment: Check for any error in it at first please, it might direct to the real error

Comment: @mappingman - I believe you can easily post those 600 lines of log as an edit to the question.